# Checking if a series of lists contain items

Tags: python, list, stock

I have a dataset that I am trying to loop through and filter for only the "exchanges" that I am looking for. I've tried `any()` but it doesn't seem to be working. Can someone please let me know what I am doing incorrectly?

My desired output is a list that contains `"NASDAQ"` or `"NYSE"`.

```
exchanges = ['NASDAQ', 'NYSE']

for i in ticker_csv:
    if any(exchanges) in i:
        print(i)
```

This prints out nothing as my conditions have not been satisfied.

Here is a sample of data within `ticker_csv`.

```
['ZVZZC', 'ZVZZC', 'NASDAQ', 'Stock', '2016-01-29', 'null', 'Active']
['ZVZZT', 'NASDAQ TEST STOCK', 'Bats', 'Stock', '2017-09-22', 'null', 'Active']
['ZWRK', 'Z-Work Acquisition Corp - Class A', 'NASDAQ', 'Stock', '2021-04-05', 'null', 'Active']
['ZWRKU', 'Z-Work Acquisition Corp - Units (1 Ord Class A & 1/3 War)', 'NASDAQ', 'Stock', '2021-01-29', 'null', 'Active']
['ZWRKW', 'Z-Work Acquisition Corp - Warrants (29/01/2026)', 'NASDAQ', 'Stock', '2021-03-24', 'null', 'Active']
['ZWZZT', 'NASDAQ TEST STOCK', 'W', 'Stock', '2017-09-22', 'null', 'Active']
['ZXYZ-A', 'NASDAQ SYMBOLOGY TEST', 'NASDAQ', 'Stock', '2016-01-19', 'null', 'Active']
['ZXZZT', 'NASDAQ TEST STOCK', 'Bats', 'Stock', '2006-07-10', 'null', 'Active']
['ZY', 'Zymergen Inc', 'Bats', 'Stock', '2021-04-22', 'null', 'Active']
['ZYME', 'Zymeworks Inc', 'MKT', 'Stock', '2017-04-28', 'null', 'Active']
['ZYNE', 'Zynerba Pharmaceuticals Inc', 'bats', 'Stock', '2015-08-05', 'null', 'Active']
['ZYXI', 'Zynex Inc', 'NASDAQ', 'Stock', '2002-12-31', 'null', 'Active']
['ZZK', '', 'NYSE ARCA', 'Stock', '2020-07-22', 'null', 'Active']
['ZZZ', 'TEST TICKER FOR UTP', 'NYSE ARCA', 'Stock', '2014-10-31', 'null', 'Active']
```

Comment: Are you only interested in exact, case-sensitive matches? What about partial matches (e.g. `NYSE ARCA`, `NASDAQ TEST STOCK`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your original code is that the builtin [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function is meant to take a sequence of Boolean values and return True if any of them are True, but you passed it a list of exchanges.

Instead, you should check whether each exchange is present in the data, and use `any` to figure out if this was True for one or more exchanges:

```py
for data in ticker_csv:
    if any(exchange in data for exchange in exchanges):
        print(data)
```

Here, `data` is a list containing several fields: the ticker symbol, full name, exchange, etc.

A better approach is to observe that the exchange is always third element of the list (index 2). So you can do something like this:

```py
for data in ticket_csv:
    exchange = data[2]
    if exchange in exchanges:
        print(data)
```

A more concise version does this filtering with the builtin [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```py
for data in filter(lambda data: data[2] in exchanges, ticker_csv):
    print(data)
```

You can also use `data[2].upper()` if you need to make a case-insensitive comparison, assuming your list of exchanges at the top is all uppercase.